# i cant found the minSdkVersion 16 in the build.gradle

Tags: flutter

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: C:\Users\El.Sa7er\AndroidStudioProjects\test_1\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug, C:\Users\El.Sa7er\AndroidStudioProjects\test_1\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

this is the error

[image]

i do not found the minSdkVersion 16
in build.gradle and i dont understand what is error

Answer (score 0):

In your code, In line number 42 is the `minSdkVersion`. Remove the line and replace it with this line. Sometimes it does not work, so clean the project and build again

```
minSdkVersion 21
```